# Two sample one-sided Kuiper Test and KS-statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, cumulative-distribution-function

With the KS-Test it is possible to conduct a two sample one-sided test between two different random samples $A$ and $B$ to test whether one CDF is larger or smaller than the other, i.e. is $CDF_A$ larger than $CDF_B$.  Standard implementations for this exist, for example MATLAB's [kstest2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest2.html).

So with respect to the above test (is $CDF_A$ larger than $CDF_B$) the `KS-statistic` will be calculated as $max(CDF_A - CDF_B)$, which can then be used to calculate the `p-value`.

Is it possible to define a two sample one-sided Kuiper Test? Essentially the question that I want to answer is that whether the two CDFs, $CDF_{A}$  and $CDF_{B}$ differ at the tails and that $CDF_{A}$ is *overall* larger than $CDF_{B}$.

For example in the image below the two CDFs differ at the tails but absolute value of $D^{+}$ is greater than absolute value of $D^{-}$. So in this case can we use the Kuiper Test to determine that one is greater than the other and how would we calculate the KS-statistic for this case?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question. My answer is *it cannot be done properly*, and I add

> Use the one-sided KS test **at your own risks**.

For instance, R offers the choice between `two.sided`, `less` or `greater`. I consider this is a mistake because it does not really explain how to interpret the one-sided case. Here is an example that will explain the main issue.

Say that $A$ and $B$ differ only by their variance. For instance assume $A \sim N(0, 1)$ and $B \sim N(0,5)$. The two distributions are different, the null hypothesis is false, so the p-value of the two-sided KS test decreases as the sample size increases. But what happens with the one-sided KS tests? Let us find out with an example.

```
set.seed(123)
A <- rnorm(100, sd=1)
B <- rnorm(100, sd=5)
ks.test(A, B, alternative="less")
# D^- = 0.44, p-value = 3.909e-09
# Null is rejected. Accept alternative A < B
ks.test(x, y, alternative="greater")
# D^+ = 0.26, p-value = 0.001159
# Null is rejected. Accept alternative A > B
```

That's right. We have accepted both `A < B` and `A > B`. And what takes the cake is that `A` and `B` are centered on the same value. Contrary to a popular belief, the one-sided versions of the KS test do not tell  whether one distribution is shifted respective to the other. What do they tell exactly? I am not sure.

The best explanation to understand what happens is your picture. You can see that in this case, both $D_+$ and $D_-$ are large, so both alternatives are accepted. It is also important to understand that by symmetry, $D = D_+$ or $D = D_-$ with probability $1/2$ each. Which statistic “won” does not tell you anything interesting.

To be honest, I do not fully understand your proposal for a one-side Kuiper test, but I foresee that it would have the same difficulties. I wrote a more detailed description of this issue on my blog (see [(mis)using the KS test for p-hacking](http://blog.thegrandlocus.com/2014/09/mis-using-the-ks-test-for-p-hacking)) and in the scientific literature (see [The signed Kolmogorov-Smirnov test: why it should not be used](https://academic.oup.com/gigascience/article-lookup/doi/10.1186/s13742-015-0048-7)). The suggestions from the reviewers Garrett Jenkinson and Desmond Campbell were to use the Wilcoxon test and the $t$ test instead.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. Yes I have also had trouble interpreting the results of one-sided KS-test. Though it seems that its used popularly because implementations are available both in Matlab and Python.
I'll take a look shortly at your blog.